# Static variables in static method in base class and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-methods, static-variables

I have these C++ classes:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    static int method()
    {
        static int x = 0;
        return x++;
    }
};

class A : public Base
{

};

class B : public Base
{

};
```

Will the `x` static variable be shared among `A` and `B`, or will each one of them have it's own independent `x` variable (which is what I want)?

Comment: Is this not something you could check quickly with a compiler and some test code?

Comment: @ttmrichter: not if there's any suspicion it might be implementation-dependent. And by the time you've checked that it isn't, you've found the answer.

Comment: @ttmrichter I suspected that the variable will be shared, but I also wanted to see if anybody has another way of solving my problem :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There will only be one instance of `x` in the entire program. A nice work-around is to use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template <class Derived>
class Base
{
protected:
    static int method()
    {
        static int x = 0;
        return x++;
    }
};

class A : public Base<A> { };
class B : public Base<B> { };
```

This will create a different `Base<T>`, and therefore a distinct `x`, for each class that derives from it.

You may also need a "Baser" base to retain polymorphism, as Neil and Akanksh point out.

Comment: Nice, you posted while I was about to submit :).

Comment: But what you don't get is polymorphism, if that is required.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that I solved a problem very similar many years ago, also with CRTP :)

Comment: @neil polymorphism is not required, I just wanted to avoid having duplicate code

Answer (score 3):

There will only be one, shared by all three classes. If you want separate instances, you will have to create separate functions in the derived classes.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure it will be shared between A and B.

If you want independent variables you can use the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern" like:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base
{
protected:
    static int method()
    {
        static int x = 0;
        return x++;
    }
};

class A : public Base<A>
{

};

class B : public Base<B>
{

};
```

Of course if you want polymorphism, you would have to define a even "Baser" class which Base derives from, as `Base<A>` is different from `Base<B>` like:

```
class Baser
{
};

template<typename Derived>
class Base : public Baser
{
protected:
    static int method()
    {
        static int x = 0;
        return x++;
    }
};

class A : public Base<A>
{};

class B : public Base<B>
{};
```

Now A and B can also be polymorphic.

Answer (score 2):

The former. Local static variables are bound to the method containing them, and `method` exists in one incarnation for all subclasses (in fact, for the whole app, even though the rest of the program does not see the method).

Answer (score 1):

The variable will be shared - it is per-function - in this case the function it belongs to is `Base::method()`.  However if `class Base` was a template class you would get one instance of the variable for each instantiation (each unique set of actual template parameters) of `class Base` template - each instantiation is a new function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making X as static then it will be shared among all the child classes. No issues with the function being static.