# Are static datamembers unique per class, in case of inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I know there is a related question: [Static variables in static method in base class and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737013/static-variables-in-static-method-in-base-class-and-inheritance)

But I am wondering if this is the same for datamembers?

suppose I have a class:

```
class A
{
protected:
   static int NUMBER;
private:
   static int OTHERNUMBER;
};

class B : public A
{
};
```

Will B have another instance than A of NUMBER?

Will B have another instance than A of OTHERNUMBER?

Comment: **OTHERNUMBER**. Why should it matter ? It isn't accessible to B.

Comment: @DumbCoder so because it isn't accessible, it doesn't matter?

Comment: I actually found a possible duplicate which I didn't see before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-members-inherited-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will B have another instance than A of NUMBER? Will B have another instance than A of OTHERNUMBER?

No, and no. Declaring a static variable in any class scope only declares a single variable, and no extra copies of it will appear in any other scope.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** There will not be a separate `B::NUMBER` or `B::OTHERNUMBER` created automatically.