# How to DRY static repetitive boilerplate code in derived classes?

Tags: c#, oop, dry, object-oriented-analysis

I have this inheritance model:

```
public class Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public static List<Action<Dog>> Augmenters = new List<Action<Dog>>();
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public static List<Action<Cat>> Augmenters = new List<Action<Cat>>();
}

// in another place of the code, augmenters are added and configured
public static void Main (string[] args) 
{
    Dog.Augmenters.Add(dog => 
    {
         // doing something with dog
    });        
    Cat.Augmenters.Add(cat => 
    {
         // doing something with cat
    });
}
```

Augmenters have a lot of static code in each `Dog`/`Cat`/etc. classes including null checking, instantiation, concurrency control, performance tuning, etc. that is exactly the same across all derived classes.

Dog augmenters should be static, because they apply to all dogs, not just one dog. So does cat augmenters, etc.

Yet they can't be migrated to `Animal` class, because augmenters of each derived class differs from other classes. If I move `Augmenters` to the `Animal` class, then each augmenter that should only belong to cats, will be applied to dogs too.

How do you DRY this type of boilerplate code?

I saw [something similar for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737013/static-variables-in-static-method-in-base-class-and-inheritance) here, it's called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to dry

```
class Program
{

    public abstract class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
    {
        public static List<Action<T>> Augmenters = new List<Action<T>>();
    }

    public class Dog : Animal<Dog>
    {

    }

    public class Cat : Animal<Cat>
    {

    }

    // in another place of the code, augmenters are added and configured
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog.Augmenters.Add(dog =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bark");
        });

        Cat.Augmenters.Add(cat =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("meow");
        });

        Dog.Augmenters[0].Invoke(new Dog());
        Cat.Augmenters[0].Invoke(new Cat());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Added an abstract method and added a constraint for its type, at least you don't have to repeat the implementation of Augementers inside the concrete classes.

Comment: OMG, it works. How that base static `Augmenters` is not shared amongst Dogs and Cast?

Comment: I made it abstract that is why it was not shared. Static will only be shared if you make it a concrete class.

Comment: This shattered a large portion of my understanding about static members. I need to study again.

Comment: I guess this works only for abstract generic base classes with a static generic member. Am I right? In any other case it fails.